# 13" Macbook Pro running Lion loses battery fast?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I bought my 13" MacBook Pro last March 27, 2011. It's 5 months old now. coconutBattery shows that I've lost 12% of the original battery capacity in just 5 months with 238 load cycles. I read in some of the questions here that one MacBook user just lost 1% of his battery capacity in **2 years**! How could I have lost such a large percentage of my battery capacity in just 5 months?

Answer (score 3):

Battery life depends greatly on use. 238 charge cycles in 5 months by most standards is pretty high. More importantly if your following the guidelines Apple has published for their battery use are you getting usage times that are in line with their estimates? Coconut battery isn't always accurate, its best to trust the built-in tools for diagnostic information.

You can also check System Information (Lion) or System Profiler (10.6) under power to get an idea of the stats on the battery. Double check to see what your Full Charge Capacity and the Charge Cycles are.

Any Apple Store or Authorized Service Provider can run diagnostics on the battery as stated by Wheat Williams. If it is faulty it's covered by your one year limited warranty.

Also check for run away processes you can check Activity Monitor, these could be draining the battery faster and driving up charge cycles.
http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1473

Answer (score 0):

Because it is under warranty, take it to an Apple Store or other authorized repair facility and have the Genius Bar guys test the battery. If it fails during the warranty period, they will replace it for free. And consider buying that AppleCare extendend warranty package so you can get telephone tech support from Apple and so you can extend your warranty coverage for two more years.

The guys at your service center can explain to you about proper SMC reset and the battery conditioning procedure.

The only way to get warranty care is to go in and ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

All batteries have natural fluctuations in the voltage and charge capacity. Also, they all degrade over time based on three general things:

1. Temperature ages batteries in a non-linear manner - exceptionally hot temperatures above (95F / 35C) will age them much faster and permanently damage them.
2. Each full charge cycle takes a little of the ability of the cell to accept a subsequent charge.
3. Batteries that fail prematurely are the exception, but most get flagged as faulty - so your mac will tell you to check your battery.

Let's assume #3 isn't happening (and you can of course take it in for service any time you want a check up). It's more important to watch how fast your Full Charge Capacity is changing over time.

Do read all the tips at http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html and do make sure to discharge it fully once a month.

The new batteries with adaptive charging circuitry [no longer require end user calibration](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1490), so just follow the tips, keep an eye and replace it if needed or it fails to meet the specifications (80% FCC at 5 years / 1000 cycles) you might be eligible for a warranty exchange (keeping in mind AppleCare is 3 years - limited warranty one year might end before the 5 years design period.)

Answer (score 0):

This is some problem with spotlight indexing server.

Disabling Spotlight in Snow Leopard solves this. Launch the Terminal and type the following command:

`sudo mdutil -a -i off`

<sup>Via [OS X Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2009/09/20/disable-spotlight-in-mac-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard/)</sup>